# Recovery compressed file from valid-length file generated by Flink BucketingSink

Tags: gzip, apache-flink

I am using a custom Gzip Compressed writer for Flink BucketingSink to write compressed text file on hdfs. I'd like to ensure the sink is exactly-once. In my case, which has hadoop < 2.7, BucketingSink will generate a valid-length file recording the valid bytes length of that file if the job has failed sometimes. It is easy to truncate a plain text file but gzip compressed file is much differents, truncating the file to the valid-length will corrupt the gzip. However use bash app "zcat" can display data without verify the format and crc32.

But in order to recover the gz file to valid, now I need to some steps: 1. download all the failed gz file 2.truncate them by valid-length. 3. zcat the truncated gz file and redirect to a text file. 4. re-compress the text file using gzip. 5. upload the modified file to hdfs

The method is very slow since I may have hundreds of file to do these work. Are there any good idea to do my work? I think some parallel distributed method may work.